# I am not able to display a base 64 encoded image?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, encode

1) Below is how, I am encoding the image--

```
StringBuilder prefixToImageEncodedString=new StringBuilder("data:image/*;base64,"); 

 InputStream in =new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("D:/resources/Australia.jpg"));
byte[] bytes=ImageIO.read(in).toString().getBytes();
String encodedfile = new String(Base64.encode(bytes), "UTF-8");
String imageBaseURL=prefixToImageEncodedString.append(encodedfile).toString();
```

I am getting following output:-

```
   data:image/*;base64,QnVmZmVyZWRJbWFnZUAxMzA5OWNjOiB0eXBlID0gNSBDb2xvck1vZGVsOiAjcGl4ZWxCaXRzID0gMjQgbnVtQ29tcG9uZW50cyA9IDMgY29sb3Igc3BhY2UgPSBqYXZhLmF3dC5jb2xvci5JQ0NfQ29sb3JTcGFjZUAxYzEyMWI2IHRyYW5zcGFyZW5jeSA9IDEgaGFzIGFscGhhID0gZmFsc2UgaXNBbHBoYVByZSA9IGZhbHNlIEJ5dGVJbnRlcmxlYXZlZFJhc3Rlcjogd2lkdGggPSAxODggaGVpZ2h0ID0gMTE5ICNudW1EYXRhRWxlbWVudHMgMyBkYXRhT2ZmWzBdID0gMg==
```

At front end (AngularJS), when I am displaying the image by setting the string, it is not displaying the image.

```
<img src="{{countryImageNew}}" class="img1">
```

Guidance is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how you read bytes from a file:

```
byte[] bytes=ImageIO.read(in).toString().getBytes();
```

ImageIO.read returns a BufferedImage.  The toString() method of BufferedImage does not return the bytes of the image, and in fact it can’t, because Java Strings are not byte containers.  They contain characters, not bytes.  Attempting to assume a String contains bytes will result in the corruption of your bytes;  specifically, String.getBytes() [encodes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html) the String’s codepoints using a charset encoding transformation.

You should not be using ImageIO at all.  You’re not doing anything image-related with the data; you just want the bytes:

```
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("D:/resources/Australia.jpg"));
```

Also, since a String is not a safe container for bytes, do not use `new String(Base64.encode(bytes), "UTF-8")`.  This *will* corrupt some of your bytes.  The correct way to create a Base 64 encoded string is with the [encodeToString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html#encodeToString-byte:A-) method:

```
String encodedfile = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
```

Comment: but this encodeToString(bytes[] bytes) is anyhow going to put the encoded file into String container,right?

Comment: @YogeshSanchihar Base64 encoded data is ASCII text, so it is safe to store in a String.

Answer (score 2):

```html
  <img src="data:image/*;base64,QnVmZmVyZWRJbWFnZUAxMzA5OWNjOiB0eXBlID0gNSBDb2xvck1vZGVsOiAjcGl4ZWxCaXRzID0gMjQgbnVtQ29tcG9uZW50cyA9IDMgY29sb3Igc3BhY2UgPSBqYXZhLmF3dC5jb2xvci5JQ0NfQ29sb3JTcGFjZUAxYzEyMWI2IHRyYW5zcGFyZW5jeSA9IDEgaGFzIGFscGhhID0gZmFsc2UgaXNBbHBoYVByZSA9IGZhbHNlIEJ5dGVJbnRlcmxlYXZlZFJhc3Rlcjogd2lkdGggPSAxODggaGVpZ2h0ID0gMTE5ICNudW1EYXRhRWxlbWVudHMgMyBkYXRhT2ZmWzBdID0gMg==">
```

I think the encoding is bad else the above ways must work.
I would suggest to do the Base64 encoding like -

`Base64.encode(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file));`

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<img [src]="countryImageNew" class="img1">
```

Wrapping `src` in brackets tells Angular to replace the value with the variable value.  Otherwise, the literal string 'countryImageNew' is what gets set as the source, not the value of the variable.

Comment: It should be `ng-src` for Angular 1.x.

Comment: You don't need `{{` `}}`

Comment: No, it is angularJS. Sorry my bad.

Comment: Ok.  I removed the `angular` tag on the question as that is for Angular2+.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<img ng-attr-src="{{countryImageNew}}" class="img1">
```

Or

```
<img ng-src="{{countryImageNew}}" class="img1">
```